# get state of ToggleButton through handler

Tags: android, togglebutton

I need to be able to access the state of a `ToggleButton` seeing is how there is no way to create methods for the specific state of a `ToggleButton`. So here is where I'm at so far:

```
ToggleButton syncSwitch = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
syncSwitch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Click!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Now all I need is some type of boolean method that can tell the handler the state of the `ToggleButton`.

Comment: syncSwitch.isChecked() not helping?

Comment: see my comment on Nikolay's answer

Answer (score 45, accepted):

What do you mean by 'create methods for the specific state'? You can get the state using [isChecked()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#isChecked%28%29).

Comment: okay, thats weird. you *are* right but I've been up and down the ToggleButton docs and I didn't see that.

Comment: Sometimes methods are hidden because are inherited from other classes. Anyway that documentation really sucks indeed, isChecked() is under android.widget.CompoundButton

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say it sucks. You just need to click the 'Inherited methods' link, and there is a very aptly named 'Checkable' interface in the list. Details are hidden by default, but that's a feature since the inheritance hierarchy for UI widgets can be pretty deep.

Comment: @ruhalde If the document had every inherited method listed as you say then I'm probably you'll complain again it sucks because methods just repeat in just about every class.

Answer (score 14):

You can also check by using togglebtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener Listener like this:

```
ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggle);
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

@Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        String.valueOf(buttonView.isChecked()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```